# Fastest (runtime) way to check if two very long arrays have at least one common element?

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I'm trying to check if two arrays have at least one common element, I've already tried a solution but it is not fast enough, it essentially consists of two nested loops, here is the code:

```
boolean oneElementChecker(int[] pArray1, int[] pArray2)
    while (i < pArray1.length) {

      j = 0;

      if (sameValueChecker)
        break;

      while (j < pArray2.length) {

        if ((pArray1[i] == pArray2[j]))
          sameValueChecker = true;

        j++;
      }

      i++;
    }

    return !sameValueChecker;
```

I'd need to know if there are ways to make this task faster.

Comment: Why is it not fast enough?

Comment: You could use `Stream API` and `parallel()` stream processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If space is not an issue, then what I probably would suggest is the use of HASHING.

First, create a hashset of elements of array pArray1. ( This would be done in O(n) time complexity).

Then, start traversing the second array, and for each element look it up in the hashset for existence (Note : hashset lookup is O(1) operation). Continue traversal until either you find an element in hashset or second array pArray2 reaches its end.

So, essentially using hashing, you would eliminate the nested loops and you final time complexity would come out to be O(n) (O(n) + O(n) ).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean fast as in short runtime, unless working with pre-sorted arrays I do not believe there is a faster way.

If you mean fast as in occupying fewer lines (faster to type I guess), a more elegant way, using Java streams is:

```
int[] array1 = ...  
int[] array2 = ...

boolean shared = Arrays.stream(array1).anyMatch(I -> Arrays.asList(array2).contains(i));
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant fastest as in short runtime, and what if the arrays are both sorted? Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

For unsorted arrays accepted answer is the better choice but if arrays are sorted then follow these steps say Arrays are A[m] and B[n]

1: Initialise indexes i = 0 and j = 0 for array A and B respectively
2: then do as below

```
if(A[i] == B[i]) {
 //print the common element
} else if(A[i] < B[i]){
 i++  //increment i
} else {
 j++; //increment j
}
```

this way you can find the common element in sorted arrays in **O(m+n)**.
Although you can also use this approach with unsorted arrays after sorting them which may take **O(mLogm + nLogn)** time complexity so better to use hashing

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `Collections.disjoint()`

```
boolean result = disjoint(asList(array1), asList(array2));
```

`result` is true if the two specified collections have no elements in common.